# "Create New Project" Button Shows Non-Android Project Creation Screen

Tags: android, android-studio, new-project

I click "Create New Project" button but it shows me the window below, instead of regular Android project creation screen. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: It is resolved by itself after some usage. But a real solution may be needed for someone else having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For issues like this, I strongly suggest you uninstall android studio and download it from [official website link](https://developer.android.com/studio/)

then do a clear install, in the process of installing, there are prompts for downloading necessary libraries, make sure your network connect is normal.